# read txt file line by line java using eclipe

Tags: java, bufferedreader

**Code:**

```
    try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("rn.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();

   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

**rn.txt file contents:**

```
12
45
78
23
45
```

**Console output:**

```
0
/
N
K
M
^

.
:
P
/
G
0

?


8
W
3
```

**Question:**
How can I read the actual data in the .txt file? Is there an issue with the code I have written?

EDIT:

[this my console output and where i put my txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUO7F.jpg)

Comment: By any chance, do you have multiple rn.txt files on your machine?

Comment: it works absolutely fine

Comment: @mazaneicha yes i have rn,txt file

Comment: @Ravi yes its work. but it give me some trash value.

Comment: I just tried your code and without single bit change. It printed as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works absolutely fine, check your .txt file is in the correct place and you don't have duplicate .txt files.

Output using your code:

```
run:
12
45
78
23
45
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: @ how can i show u my console. stack over flow not allowed print screen :(  it just give me trash value

Comment: You need to check where your are placing the file, and whether you have duplicate files @susan

Comment: actually my program is under GUI . this is where my txt file located . "${workspace_loc:/GuiRandomNumber/rn}"

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("F://angular pdf/rn.txt");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

                String line =bufferedReader.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                   line= bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: The code SO has written is fine, it doesn't need changing, what improvements does this make?

Comment: @Rajesh F://angular pdf/ ? i do not have that path . it just a simple txt file. are u using eclipse to compile ?

Comment: replace above  path with ur path were ur file located